# SQL Subquery with Conditional Modulo

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've put together this query and I am struggling to see why it is returning the full quantity of `LINES` rather than just the `LINES` that have an odd number of `ITEMS`.  Ex: right now I have 2 `LINES` where `COMPLETED` is marked `True`.  One of them has an odd number of `ITEMS` and one of them has an even number of `ITEMS` but the query is still returning 2 despite my conditional.  What's wrong with my query?

```
SET @linesCompleted = (SELECT Count([so_line_number]) AS LINES 
                       FROM   [aof_order_line_queue] 
                       WHERE  [completed] = 'True' 
                              AND (SELECT Count([serial_number]) AS ITEMS 
                                   FROM   [aof_order_items] 
                                   WHERE  so_line_number IN (SELECT 
                                          [so_line_number] 
                                                             FROM 
                                          [aof_boxes_lines] 
                                                             WHERE 
                                          [aof_boxes_id] = 880)) % 2 = 1)
```

The goal here is to compute the quantity of `LINES` that a box contains that are an odd number.

I suspect the problem could the `IN` subquery returning two results, though one result should be odd and one result should be even.

Comment: Where's the part where the subquery is correlated to the outer query?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm not sure I understand your question.  This is the entire query.

Comment: I can't see how your query that does the counting (and comes up with an odd number) is linked to the outer query that wants to know if the resut is odd.. Example `SELECT * FROM person p WHERE EXISTS(SELECT null FROM exams WHERE student_name = p.name)` the two queries are linked together because the inner query has data that is compared to the outer query.. If you don't have this link, then you don't get the result you expect - what links your queries together?

Comment: You might be better off dumping this XY Problem (http://xyproblem.info) and just giving us the tables and example data. I suspect a simpler solution can be had with `... GROUP BY something HAVING COUNT(*) % 2 =1`

Comment: I didn't think a subquery needs any direct link to the parent query in this case.  All I want are the results of the inner query to compare.

Comment: But if queries don't link together, then you get things you don't expect: `SELECT * FROM person p WHERE EXISTS(SELECT null FROM exams WHERE student_name = 'John')` - while the school has no student called John, the query returns no results. As soon as a John enrolls at the school, the query suddenly returns EVERY student, regardless of their name. `SELECT * FROM person WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM address) % 2 = 1` will return every person when the addresses table has an odd number of addresses and no person when it has even..It cannot find people who only have an odd number of addresses

Comment: I don't understand how person links with address, you have no direct reference of which person belongs to which address.

Comment: Between the horrible formatting and lack of any details nobody can really help here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange the details are in the description and in the code.  Not much more to add.

Comment: @SeanLange I cleaned up the formatting.  Does it meet your approval now? lol

Comment: You could add ddl, sample data and the desired output for the sample data. This is how forums like this work. It is not about my approval, it is about providing the details so others can help you. I can tell you the reason it is not working is because you don't correlate the subqueries. But I think you have over complicated this. If you can post the information so others have something to work with you would already have an answer.

Comment: @SeanLange again, it's in the details.  Imo, I was pretty clear about the desired output from the inputs given.  If I am doing it wrong, then that's exactly why I'm here, to understand how and why I am doing it wrong.,

Comment: And I can help if you could be troubled to post sample data and such so I have a query I can work with. I would argue that you didn't post any details because the topic is about data and you posted exactly ZERO pieces of data. Since you seem to be unwilling to put much effort into this I will answer the question you asked "What's wrong with my query?". Simple, you need to correlate your subqueries.

Comment: Cor, there's an echo in here :)

Comment: Sample data or at the very very least the schema of your three tables. We can guess at the relationship between them then and help out. In short though, you either need to join your data or you need to correlate your subquery to your main query...as has been said over and over again.

Comment: "I don't understand how person links with address, you have no direct reference of which person belongs to which address." - yes, that's the point i've been making all along about YOUR query. I think you may have pushed this XY problem into "sunk cost fallacy" territory; dump this query, post some example data and ask a question that is the actual problem you're trying to solve ("i need to know which orders have an odd number of detail lines") and *not* the problem with the solution you've devised ("I've got this query which i think will solve my problem but it doesn't work - why?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the lack of correlation in the outer query to the inner query.

You are asking it to count the number of lines in aof_order_line_queue where (something that's not related to the line) is true. So the thing in the parenthesis is either true or false for the whole data set, not for each line. If it's true, it will count all the lines. If it's false, it will return 0.

You have to add something like

```
AND aof_order_items.queue_id = aof_order_line_queue.queue_id
```

to your inner query.

Comment: Each `SERIAL_NUMBER` has an associated `SO_LINE_NUMBER`.  Each box can have several `SO_LINE_NUMBER`s.  I want to count the `SO_LINE_NUMBER`s for each one that exists in the box and has an odd numbered occurrence of `SERIAL_NUMBER`.

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF GOD, JIM, POST SOME SAMPLE DATA and an expected result so we can write a query that works instead of trying to polish a turd :)